# Create Chrome App for Chrome Store with PWA

Tags: google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

I've searched Google looking for the possibility of creating a Chrome App from an existing PWA that can be listed on Google Chrome Store.
Please I want to know if it's possible and how I can go about it plus possible resources I can check.